# Mercurial Repo : hg verify issue : "first damaged changeset appears to be 3270"

Tags: version-control, migration, mercurial, corruption

Running Hg verify command on Mercurial repo returns below output:

> hg verify

```
checking changesets
checking manifests
 manifest@3270: changeset refers to unknown revision c33e42cadbba
crosschecking files in changesets and manifests
checking files
 WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/labels.properties@3270: c7287124bd0a not in manifests
checked 5835 changesets with 100225 changes to 78258 files
2 integrity errors encountered!
(first damaged changeset appears to be 3270)
```

How can this issue be fixed ?

Comment: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RepositoryCorruption#Dirstate_corruption

Answer (score 1):

'''
Used hg strip 3270 to remove the changeset.

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/StripExtension

select changeset you want to remove > right click > Modify History > Strip … > press Strip button.

Now the hg verify does not complain about integrity issues.

This can be done via command line also

hg strip --keep --force --verbose --nobackup 3270

'''